# Exact solution of the evolution operator generated by a linearly driven quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution

Consider a linearly driven quantum harmonic oscillator with the time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t) = \hbar \omega a^{\dagger} a + i \hbar \left[ \varepsilon(t) a^{\dagger} - \varepsilon^*(t) a \right]$, where $\varepsilon(t)$ is an arbitrary complex-valued function. By moving into the interaction picture, solving for the dynamics there, and then moving back to the original picture, I can obtain the following analytic expression for the evolution operator generated by $H(t)$:
$$U(t) = e^{-i\omega t a^{\dagger} a} e^{\int_0^t \mathrm{d}\tau \left( \varepsilon(\tau) e^{i\omega \tau} a^{\dagger} - \varepsilon^*(\tau) e^{-i\omega \tau} a \right)} e^{i \phi(t)},$$
where $\phi(t)$ is an irrelevant phase factor. Now my question is, is there a way to combine the first two factors into a single term, by which I mean $U(t) = e^{G(t)} e^{i \phi(t)}$? Note that I'm not looking for a series form of $G(t)$, but I wanna know whether a clean analytic formula for $G(t)$ exists.

Comment: Have you considered the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)? None of the special cases seem to apply, so this would just give an expansion in terms of nested commutators...

Comment: @go_science Thank you for your reply. Yes, I did, and so I think maybe there is some trick that I don't know to avoid using the BCH formula blindly.